# Eliminate Null Output row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a simple select query that gives output according to a date range:

```
Declare @prevDate as Date

@prevDate = (Select Max(myDates) From Top40Table Where mydates < '2012/05/03' And          PrimID=1)

Select 
    myDates, (P1/(Lag(P1) Over (Order by myDates))-1) As myRet
From 
    Top40Table
Where 
    (myDates Between @prevDate and '2012/05/10')
    And PrimID = 1
```

This is a typical result set:

```
myDates     myRet
2012-05-02  NULL
2012-05-03  -0.0173786439241019
2012-05-04  -0.0268509853003636
2012-05-07  -0.00941786149400936
2012-05-08  -0.0134267235683988
2012-05-09  0.00633992501692782
2012-05-10  0.0203276794347731
```

The select query is correct and does what it is supposed to do, getting prevDate 2012/05/02 in order to do the calculation. But I do not want the 2012/05/02 row that has NULL output in the `myRet` column. I can insert the `myDates` and `myRet` data into a temporary table (`@TempTable`) and then a select only `myDates` and `myRet` where `myRet` is not Null from that table.

Is there a simpler way to do this without having to create a `@TempTable` and then another select query? I use SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  myDates
        ,       (P1/(Lag(P1) Over (Order by myDates))-1) As myRet
        from    Top40Table
        where   myDates Between @prevDate and '2012/05/10'
                and PrimID = 1
        ) as SubQueryAlias
where   myRet is not null
```

Comment: Thank you Andomar.  For interest, why is it necessary to add as SubQueryAlias?

Comment: Yes, SQL Server always requires a subquery alias. Even if it's not needed to disambiguate columns.

Answer (score -1):

@Andomar , it is not a subquery, this is a derived table which is always starts FROM and subquery starts after WHERE clause.